# Is there a way to get (python) script output while running using org-mode

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

I'm writing small bits of code inside `org-mode` files. This bits of code are slow (copy files from remote machines) and I wish to see how the copy progress (sometimes the connection to the remote machine fails and I wish to know). For that, I want to print the serial number of the currently accessed file.

Org-mode's code-block have two problems with this:

1. It places the either the printed messages or the returned variable in the results part of the block.
2. It does so only once the code ends.

Is there a way to get the printed output to a separated, live variable?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'd be interested too.

Comment: I'd try to advise `org-babel-get-src-block-info` so that if it encounters some special option in the code block description, it would start the timer to monitor the process - from there on you'd be on your own writing the updating / monitoring stuff, but that seems like a plausible place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Reopening sys.stdout so that it is flushed should help.

See [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print), and this blog post:

http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/python-tips-and-tricks-flushing-stdout.html